# visual studio custom install action doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I created a Setup Project copied all my files over to the application folder, included an accessdbengine.exe file and created a Custom Install Action using the accessdbengine.exe file with the argument set to /passive

When I run the setup it shows that it installs the accessdbengine.exe but it doesnt look like the regular installer when manually running the accessdbengine.exe, it also doesn't show up in programs like it does when manually installing it.

My app doesn't work unless the accessdbengine.exe is installed, if I manually install it then it works. So it doesn't seem like the Custom Install Action is really working. Anyone have any ideas?

Link to the msaccessdbengine file I am referring to. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Did you create visual studio installer setup project including your accessdbengine.exe file?

Comment: Yes I did and I could see it trigger the install... but didn't seem like it actually installed. I was able to get it to work without that though... I just changed the Provider to Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; and now it installs fine and works fine without the need for that accessdbengine.exe installed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my Provider from Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; to Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; solved my problem.